# IE8 - IFRAME causes refresh of entire page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I have an uploader file based on IFRAME. It works fine with Firefox and Google Chrome but with Internet Explorer 8, when you send a file the entire page, is refreshed. Following my code:

JS:

```
  function test(){
     iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");  
     iframe.name = "iframe_upload";
     iframe.id = "iframe_upload"; //some browsers target by id not name
     document.body.appendChild(iframe);
     document.getElementById("test").target = "iframe_upload";
  }
```

HTML:

```
<form id="test" method="post" target="iframe_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="javascript:test()" action="test.php">
  <input name="image" type="file" /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return from `onsubmit` action:

```
onsubmit="return test();"
```

and return `false` from function:

```
function test(){
   iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");  
   iframe.name = "iframe_upload";
   iframe.id = "iframe_upload"; //some browsers target by id not name
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);
   document.getElementById("test").target = "iframe_upload";
   return false;
}
```